# Unable to get page content for oneNote Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/pages/{id}/content

is returning

```
{
    "error": {
         "code": "19999",
        "message": "Something failed, the API cannot share any more information at the time of the request.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "571dbc03-154a-4ece-aa7b-1fb05c8c31ce",
            "date": "2017-07-11T22:49:01"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  It's important to be clear about what you are asking and to provide a code example that reproduces the error in order to get a good answer.  See [how to ask] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry Namrata. Looks like we have a bug. Thanks for reporting. I will fix it and get back to you soon.

Comment: thank you, if/when you know the ETA, please let me know.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The issue has been fixed. Can you re-try and let me know? Thanks